# Adding wrapper for graphQL queries - HOC or Render props

Tags: reactjs, graphql, react-props

I am trying to do a wrapper for the graphQL queries, I tried this

```
const GQLWrapper = ({ query, children}) => (
  <Query query={query}>
    {({ loading, error, data }) => {
      if (loading) {
        return null
      }
      if (error) {
        <QueryError />
      }
      const { gqlData } = data.page    
      return (
        <div>
          {children}
        </div>
      )
    }}
  </Query>
)
```

but i don't understand how to use [render props](https://reactjs.org/docs/render-props.html) to pass the data to the child component.

Also if it is a better solution to use HOC, please let me know (when should one be used or the other). Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just make your children a function and pass the data there

```js
return <div>{children(gqlData)}</div>;
```

When you use your wrapper you do:

```js
<GQLWrapper query={myquery}>
  {(gqlData) => <SomeComponent data={gqlData} />}
</GQLWrapper>
```